# PostgreSQL window function "lag()" only pulls from current resultset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm making a stock ticker as a learning experience for PostgreSQL and AngularJS.

In my ticker query, I attempt to discover the change in price from the previous day. I'm implementing the DB queries in PHP right now for ease of testing and I'll port to AngularJS later.

**DB Setup**

```
prices
--pk
--fund (foreign key to funds.pk)
--price
--price_date

funds
--pk
--fund_name
--summary
```

**Query**
Get the latest price and the price before it (as well as other info) for each fund with an entry in the prices table.
This $query is a single line in my PHP file.

```
$query = 'SELECT prices.price_date, 
prices.price, 
(lag(prices.price) over (ORDER BY prices.price_date DESC)) as last_price, 
prices.fund, 
funds.fund_name 
FROM prices 
INNER JOIN funds ON prices.fund=funds.pk 
WHERE price_date=(SELECT price_date FROM prices ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1)';
```

**Result**

```
[
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"17.5901","last_price":null,"fund":"1","fund_name":"L Income"},
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"22.8859","last_price":"17.5901","fund":"2","fund_name":"L 2020"},
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"24.6693","last_price":"22.8859","fund":"3","fund_name":"L 2030"},
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"26.1456","last_price":"24.6693","fund":"4","fund_name":"L 2040"},
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"14.7756","last_price":"26.1456","fund":"5","fund_name":"L 2050"},
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"14.8181","last_price":"14.7756","fund":"6","fund_name":"G Fund"},
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"16.93","last_price":"14.8181","fund":"7","fund_name":"F Fund"},
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"26.369","last_price":"16.93","fund":"8","fund_name":"C Fund"},
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"35.9595","last_price":"26.369","fund":"9","fund_name":"S Fund"},
{"price_date":"2015-09-08","price":"24.0362","last_price":"35.9595","fund":"10","fund_name":"I Fund"}
]
```

As you can see, the lag() window function is only drawing on the current resultset for pulling the previous record's prices.price field.

I am at a loss now. Does anyone have guidance?

Comment: In my opinion you should add the partition by clause to get the previous day's price of the same fund, not the arbitrary fund, like this: over `(partition by prices.fund ORDER BY prices.price_date DESC)`

Comment: That’s how `lag` is supposed to work. You may be able to get the behavior you *want* by having a broader filter and using `lag` with that, and using that as a subquery, filtering it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want the previous day's price for the `fund`.  This requires a `partition by` clause:

```
SELECT p.price_date, p.price, 
       lag(p.price) over (PARTITION BY p.fund ORDER BY p.price_date DESC) as last_price, 
       p.fund, p.fund_name 
FROM prices p INNER JOIN
     funds f
     ON p.fund = f.pk ;
```

If you then want this only for the last date, then use a subquery:

```
SELECT pf.*
FROM (SELECT p.price_date, p.price, 
             lag(p.price) over (PARTITION BY p.fund ORDER BY p.price_date DESC) as last_price, 
             p.fund, p.fund_name 
      FROM prices p INNER JOIN
           funds f
           ON p.fund = f.pk
     ) pf
WHERE price_date = (SELECT price_date FROM prices ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1);
```

The `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the analytic functions, so the filtering affects which record (if any) is chosen by the `LAG()`.  Note:  this assumes that the max `price_date` is the same for all funds, but this is the logic in the question.

Comment: Thanks so much!! After you showed me the answer, I went to the docs looking and found a more detailed discussion of PARTITION BY. It's in the first salary example:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Of note: The final SQL query uses either `lead()` or sorts within the subquery by `p.price_date ASC` -- I don't fully understand why. If I use `lag()` and `DESC` in the subquery, `last_price` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare it to the price from previous day, you should use a conditional so it always picks up values from the previous day.

```
SELECT prices.price_date, 
prices.price, 
case when price_date = (select max(prices_date) from prices) then 
lag(prices.price) over (ORDER BY prices.price_date) 
end as last_price, 
prices.fund, 
funds.fund_name 
FROM prices 
INNER JOIN funds ON prices.fund = funds.pk 
WHERE price_date=(SELECT price_date FROM prices ORDER BY price_date DESC LIMIT 1)
```